# Why is this code throwing NumberFormatException Invalid int: ""?

Tags: android, android-edittext, numberformatexception

I'm trying to get it to if a user doesn't enter a value in the EditText boxes, the initial value is set to 0 (to prevent the crash error NumberFormatException Invalid int: "") which is thrown assuming because there is no integer value to read, since the user didn't input one in this case.

I've tried a number of things most recently this:

```
String boozeAmount = boozeConsumed.getText().toString();

        if (boozeAmount == "" || boozeAmount == null){
            boozeConsumed.setText("0");
            boozeAmount = boozeConsumed.getText().toString();
        }
        int boozeOz = Integer.parseInt(boozeAmount) * 12;
        double beerCalc = boozeOz * 4 * 0.075;
```

But it seems to still throw the same error, not sure why the int values aren't being set to 0?

Throwing error on

```
int boozeOz = Integer.parseInt(boozeAmount) * 12;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (boozeAmount == "" || boozeAmount == null){
```

It can be easily deduced from your explanation that this particular `if` statement is returning `true`, that's why your string value is not being set to "0".

Strings in Java are not primitive, i.e they cannot be compared with the comparator `==`.
You need to use the method `equals` to compare strings, as in `boozeAmount.equals("")`.

Apache Commons has a [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) utility that can check if strings are null or empty.
Check out `isEmpty` and `isBlank`.

Answer (score 1):

you dont compare strings with == you compare it with .equals()

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
if (boozeAmount.equals("") || boozeAmount == null)
```

Although it's probably safest to also do:

```
 if (...)
 {
   // just set it to zero and skip even trying to parse
 }
 else
 {
   // do the actual parsing
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are fetching a string value from the EditText always trim that variable to avoid any `white spaces` from EditText.

```
String boozeAmount = boozeConsumed.getText().toString().trim();                  // apply Trim

// Always compare strings with `equals()` method in Java & Android
if ( boozeAmount.equals( "" ) || boozeAmount == null )
{
    boozeConsumed.setText("0");
    boozeAmount = boozeConsumed.getText().toString();
}
    int boozeOz = Integer.parseInt(boozeAmount) * 12;
    double beerCalc = boozeOz * 4 * 0.075;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if it's blank and then fill it with 0 and *then* get the input.

Also, always compare string values with `.equals` and use `.trim()` to get rid of whitespace so that it's recognized as invalid input as well.

```
if (boozeConsumed.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
// if (boozeConsumed.length() == 0) { // doesn't consider spaces though
    boozeConsumed.setText("0");
}

String boozeAmount = boozeConsumed.getText().toString();
int boozeOz = Integer.parseInt(boozeAmount) * 12;
double beerCalc = boozeOz * 4 * 0.075;
```

---

Or just do this, because you don't need to parse it to an integer if you know there's nothing there:

```
String boozeAmount = boozeConsumed.getText().toString();

int boozeOz = 0;
double beerCalc = 0; 

if (boozeAmount.trim().equals("") || boozeAmount == null){
    boozeConsumed.setText("0");
    boozeAmount = boozeConsumed.getText().toString();
} else {
    // only parse it if there's something there
    boozeOz = Integer.parseInt(boozeAmount) * 12;
    beerCalc = boozeOz * 4 * 0.075;
}
```