# NumberFormatException Invalid Long with Calendar

Tags: android, exception, calendar, numberformatexception

I am having problems with this NumberFormatException Invalid Long. The log cat is showing that the error is coming from the `Long.parseLong` part of the method.

```
  public static String getDateTimeStr(String p_time_in_millis) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
    Date l_time = new Date(Long.parseLong(p_time_in_millis));
    return sdf.format(l_time);
}
```

Can someone tell me why this code works fine when I fetch and display the data in certain calendars then in other calendars on my device I get this `NumberFormatException Invalid Long` please?

**Edit:** Here is the rest of the code…

```
private void getEvents() {

    Uri l_eventUri;
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> allStudents = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
        l_eventUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
    } else {
        l_eventUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
    }

    String[] l_projection = new String[]{"title", "dtstart", "dtend"};

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor l_managedCursor = this.managedQuery(l_eventUri, l_projection, "calendar_id=" + m_selectedCalendarId, null, "dtstart DESC, dtend DESC");

    if (l_managedCursor.moveToFirst()) {


        int l_colTitle = l_managedCursor.getColumnIndex(l_projection[0]);
        int l_colBegin = l_managedCursor.getColumnIndex(l_projection[1]);
        int l_colEnd = l_managedCursor.getColumnIndex(l_projection[2]);

        String l_title = String.valueOf(l_colTitle);
        String l_begin = Integer.toString(l_colBegin);
        String l_end = Integer.toString(l_colEnd);

        do {

            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    

            l_title = l_managedCursor.getString(l_colTitle);
            l_begin = getDateTimeStr(l_managedCursor.getString(l_colBegin));
            l_end = getDateTimeStr(l_managedCursor.getString(l_colEnd));

            map.put("eventTitles", l_title);
            map.put("event_begin", l_begin);
            map.put("event_end", l_end);
            allStudents.add(map);


        } while (l_managedCursor.moveToNext());

        l_managedCursor.close();

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, allStudents, R.layout.notice_layout, new String[] { "eventTitles", "event_begin", "event_end" }, new int[] { R.id.tvTitle, R.id.tvBody, R.id.tvTeacherCode}); 
        listViewCalendar.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


}
```

**Edit 2:**

For some reason the code works fine without this line of code so I've nailed it down to this line of code.

```
l_end = getDateTimeStr(l_managedCursor.getString(l_colEnd));
```

Why does the `l_colEnd` get caught up in an `NumberFormatExcetion`? When the following line of code could be also caught up in the same `NumberFormatException` because it is enquiring about the same int format?

```
l_begin = getDateTimeStr(l_managedCursor.getString(l_colBegin));
```

Thank you too all who have helped. The other interesting thing also is when I add this

```
int l_cnt = 0;
do {
   ++l_cnt;
} while (l_managedCursor.moveToNext() && l_cnt < 100);
```

to the `while` clause as shown below at the end of the following code the app works fine with no lines of code throwing a `NumberFormatException`..

```
if (l_managedCursor.moveToFirst()) {

        int l_cnt = 0;

        int l_colTitle = l_managedCursor.getColumnIndex(l_projection[0]);
        int l_colBegin = l_managedCursor.getColumnIndex(l_projection[1]);
        int l_colEnd = l_managedCursor.getColumnIndex(l_projection[2]);

        String l_title = String.valueOf(l_colTitle);
        String l_begin = Integer.toString(l_colBegin);
        String l_end = Integer.toString(l_colEnd);

        do {

            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    

            l_title = l_managedCursor.getString(l_colTitle);
            l_begin = getDateTimeStr(l_managedCursor.getString(l_colBegin));
            l_end = getDateTimeStr(l_managedCursor.getString(l_colEnd));

            map.put("eventTitles", l_title);
            map.put("event_begin", l_begin);
            map.put("event_end", l_end);
            allStudents.add(map);

            ++l_cnt;

        } while (l_managedCursor.moveToNext() && l_cnt < 100);
```

Comment: Impossible to know without knowing what p_time_in_millis is. Try logging the value of that string, and you'll probably get your own answer.

Comment: Hi bruce its coming from these lines of code                    l_begin = getDateTimeStr(l_managedCursor.getString(l_colBegin));
l_end = getDateTimeStr(l_managedCursor.getString(l_colEnd));          thoughts?

Comment: the error is because the string p_time_in_millis in getDateTimestr contains other characters than just numeric , so when u parse the string to long JVM does not find the string to be a complete numeric string. Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896610/why-is-this-code-throwing-numberformatexception-invalid-int?rq=1

Comment: Thanks guys.. have worked on it over the last 3 hours and have updated my question. Please let me know what you think.. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone tell me why this code works fine when I fetch and display
>   the data in certain calendars then in other calendars on my device I
>   get this NumberFormatException Invalid Long please?
>
> Date l_time = new Date(Long.parseLong(p_time_in_millis));

IMO. This code is "bad" code.

Why? You try to fetch unknown data from unchecked sources

`"content://com.android.calendar/events"` and `"content://calendar/events"`

Almost everybody can access calendars and save whatever he like... Sadly there is no rule there for using this! So making a wild guess an app is using this event column to save data in another that your expected format.

> Regarding the check l_cnt < 100, where fail stops

It's not failing because the error happens to 101 event or later!

---

My solution would to check my data, and never trust that other apps will act as I expected or as they should.

So I suggest to change `getDateTimeStr` method as follows:

```
   public static String getDateTimeStr(String p_time_in_millis) {
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
      long timestamp = 0;
      try {
         timestamp = Long.parseLong(p_time_in_millis)
      } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
         Log.w("getDateTimeStr", "Cannot convert '"+p_time_in_millis+"' to long");
         e.printStackTrace(); // Prints full error exception
      }
      Date l_time = new Date(timestamp);
      return sdf.format(l_time);
   }
```

Remove the `l_cnt < 100` check and leave the code to run checking your logcat! You will now have a better overview of what is happening and also your **bad** data dates will be 1/1/1970 (due to 0 timestamp) code can be changed responsively in order to handle that dates which does not have the expected format.

Some ideas for handling errors:

- Make `getDateTimeStr` throw an exception to the `getEvents()` which could catch it and ignore the event with the unexpected data. (Handling logic, ignoring what I cannot understand.)
- Recognize the format of the `p_time_in_millis` in each different case and use different `DATE_TIME_FORMAT` types regarding the exact format of each event. Okey, that's needs a lot of investigation and still can fail. Also you have to add the case that the format is still unknown so maybe ignore it or use a default value in order not to crash.

Generally, you always try to write a stable app that will not fail if another app saves data in a different format (because it like so or due to its own bug)

Comment: Thanks Madlymad, I'm a rookie at this and have only been programming for 1 and half years now so am totally lost when you say Why? You try to fetch unknown data from unchecked sources

"content://com.android.calendar/events" and "content://calendar/events"                                           and yep totally agree this is bad code cause I got it from another source and tried to reuse it for my own app. Thank you for your answer it helped a lot =)  it actually solved my problem…

Comment: Always examples does not provide error checks, in order to be more clear what is done to them ;) But in real apps you usually have to validate every single data either it is from the web or an external DB.